# Add the image before the web address?

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, browser

how to add a the image before the address in the browsers "address bar" to your own page? (im using Chrome)
I want for example a glass of beer as my image. I got the image (beer.png). How to add it?

[image: picture on top left part of my browser]

and how to reach other pages images to include those as a link to that page? 
thanks!

Comment: It's called a "favicon(.ico)". Google it. For some browsers (mostly mobile devices such as iPads or iPhones) can make us of hi-res favicons. Here's a good [link](http://davidwalsh.name/retina-favicons) to help you out.

Comment: @BramVanroy you didn't got the question :) OP is aware about the favicon, but he needs besides the address bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put a favicon

Put this

```
<link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

on the head section of your page.

You will have something like this

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Your Website</title>
</head>
```

Comment: PNG can be used, too, of course: `type="image/png"`

Answer (score 2):

The favicon where you want to show is not possible as Chrome **AS WELL AS** Firefox uses that to show whether the website uses `HTTPS` or not.

So short answer is you **CANNOT DO THAT**.

---

And if you want to simply add a favicon to your website, than you can refer the answer links shared by [@Robin Green](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162180/add-the-image-before-the-web-address/20162223#comment30054389_20162180)